# Anchor link scrollbar starting in middle

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, anchor

Sorry I have tried searching but I think my problem is pretty specific.

So I have 2 divs, one with anchor tags, then main content div. In the main content div I have the following script to hide differen't divs within the content div to hide and show active anchor links.

```
 function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
      var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
            for(var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
                  name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");
                  if (name == 'newboxes') {
                        if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                        newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';
                  }
                  else {
                        newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';
                  }
            }
      }
    }
```

Everything is working fine, but when I scroll down after clicking one anchor, and then I click another anchor, it's scrolled to where I was on the last anchor. I have tried adding the following to the anchor links with no luck:

```
    function scrollWin()
{
scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated

Update:

```
<a href="#x1" onclick="showonlyone('newboxes1')"><span class="subsection1">1 Introduction</span></a><br>
<a href="#x1.1" onclick="showonlyone('newboxes2')"><span class="subsection">1.1 What version am I using?</span></a>
```

Newboxes div:

```
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes38">
```

CSS:

```
#bigbox {
position: fixed;
margin-left:31.7%;
margin-right:auto;
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
width:53.25%;
height: 89%;
background-color:#fff;
padding:2em;
border-right:1px grey solid;
border-left:1px grey solid;
padding-bottom: 3em;
```

}

Comment: Is there any additional code different to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d52k62vp/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    var newboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var x=0; x<newboxes.length; x++) {
        name = newboxes[x].getAttribute("class");
        if (name == 'newboxes') {
            if (newboxes[x].id == thechosenone) {
                newboxes[x].style.display = 'block';                        
            } else {
                newboxes[x].style.display = 'none';                        
            }
            newboxes[x].scrollTop = 0; //scrolls all divs to the top
        }
    }
}
```

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d52k62vp/5/

Comment: I've changed my function scrollWin() using this and still not working. Thanks.

Comment: That helped thanks, one more thing, it works, but you have to click off and then on the link again for it to work.

So:

Click on link 1, scroll down, click on link 2, it's scrolled down, click on link 1 again, it scrolls up.

Comment: Can you post the code for one of the "newboxes" please?

Comment: Yeah, i just added my css to that js fiddle and it works too, no idea why it doesn't on my page. I have a feeling its something to do with my divs stretching to the size of the window? Thanks anyway, I'll try and work from your example

Comment: It doesn't matter that it is the size of the window, it will still scroll to the top. There has to be another factor. If you can replicate the error in a jsfiddle, please do so and post it so I can look at it.